# jquery ajax incorrectly adding semi-colon to passed data

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, knockout-2.0

I have the following simple example where I have 3 types of settings that I am passing via ajax.

```
var settings = {
    "one" : "V&T",
    "two" : "V & T",
    "three" : "V&T100",
    "four" : "V&T1"
};

return $.ajax({
    url  : myUrl,
    type : "POST",
    data : {"settings" : settings},
});
```

When I check my post data in php these are rendered as follows

```
Array(
[settings] => Array
    (
        [one] => V&T
        [two] => V & T
        [three] => V&T100;
        [four] => V&T1;
    )
)
```

Note how for three and four I now havethe semi-colon(;) added to these variables.

Is there any kind of work around for this or has anyone a solution? This is a very simplified example, my full code actually uses knockout to render the settings.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter with `global_xss_filtering` turned on?

Comment: @AmalMurali yes I'm using Codeigniter and global_xss_filtering is turned on, but I can't change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter global xss filtering was encoding the ampersand and adding the trailing semicolon(;).

As I was unable to disable the global xss filtering I opted to use the raw php://input to get my data.

Comment: you should not turn off `global_xss_filtering`, instead you should unescape your data.

Comment: @AnasNakawa - thanks, I found your comment to be of absolutely no help at all. If you read my actual post you will notice that I had already stated that I was not turning off the global_xss_filtering!